# Error al instalar swagger en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, swagger

He creado una Web Api e instalado Swagger en mi Proyecto hecho en Visual Studio con C#.

Al momento de correr mi proyecto me aparece el siguiente error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

En mi Web.config he puesto las siguientes dependencias:

```
    <runtime>
         <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
           <dependentAssembly>
             <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
             <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
         </assemblyBinding>   
</runtime>
```

**Visual Studio 2013
Framework 4.5
Swagger 5.5.3**

Pero aún asi me sigue marcado el mismo error, ¿Alguna idea?

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba actualizando y reinstalando WebAPI desde la consola de **Nuget**

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall
```

Comment: Una vez que re-instale el WebAPI tuve que cambiar las versiones en el webconfig y funcionó. Gracias.  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir. Saludos :D